# Can anyone explain this class constructor with no code body?

Tags: c#, constructor, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

More of a why than a how, but how is this possible as I am under the impression all constructors require a code block - even if there's nothing in it?

The following code is taken directly from the class definition for

> AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser

The constructors for the `IdentityUser` class do not have a code block in the definition? Can anybody explain?

```
public class IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUser, IUser<string>
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Constructor which creates a new Guid for the Id
    public IdentityUser();

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Constructor that takes a userName
    public IdentityUser(string userName);
}
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409520/bodyless-constructor-in-non-abstract-c-sharp-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fake code generated by Visual Studio's Go To Definition service, from a assembly metadata.

It isn't real code and won't actually compile.

You can see this in a comment on top of the "file".